# SWIFT IOS send OneSignal notification across app

Tags: swift, onesignal

My notification works fine when a user is sending a notification to another user in the same app.

```
let userPushId = order?.pushId

    let jsonMessage: [AnyHashable: Any]! = ["contents": ["en": "is taking your order"],
                "headings": ["en": self.myUserName ?? "Driver"], "include_player_ids": [userPushId],
                "ios_badgeType": "Increase", "ios_badgeCount": 1]

            OneSignal.postNotification(jsonMessage, onSuccess: { _ in
                print("from\(self.myUserName ?? "") to \(userPushId)")
            }, onFailure: { _ in

                print("Notification could not be delivered")
            })
```

However, when I need to send notification from a Driver (one app) to a user (another app) with the code above, the user won't receive the notification. I believe I need to add rest API Key or OneSignal app id into the code above, but I don't know how. Could anyone tell me what codes I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I have found the solution. Just add:  ""app_id": "the app id",

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
        ) -> Bool
```

in above method , you need to setup this all params

```
// must be Replace 'YOUR_APP_ID' with your OneSignal App ID.
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
appId: "YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID",
handleNotificationAction: nil,
settings: onesignalInitSettings)
```